# Can not instal laravel

Tags: laravel, composer-php

The "http://repo.packagist.org/p/guzzlehttp/psr7%24a1ea6550f2764cbd6a29394f3c79fe41efb9cfc4bc22558b00a4a0e5573d63c1.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
http://repo.packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date

Answer (score 0):

Is this on `composer install` within a project or up creation with something like `laravel new laravel.local`?

If it's in a current project, try deleting the `composer.lock` file and deleting the `/vendor` folder, then running `composer clearcache`, then `composer dump-autoload`, and then finally reinstall all the vendor packages with `composer install`